# Return a single object that contains all the fields of the original objects

Tags: javascript

Write a function that accepts any number of objects, and returns a single object that contains all the fields of the original objects.

If the same key is found in several objects, you should leave the meaning that was first met. My solution does not give the correct result.

```js
function zip() {
    const appliedValues = Object.assign({}, ...objects);
    return appliedValues;
}

const objects = [
  { foo: 5, bar: 6 },
  { foo: 13, baz: -1 } // foo - repeating key
];

zip(...objects); // I expect { foo: 5, bar: 6, baz: -1 }
```

Make the record look like this: `{ foo: 5, bar: 6, baz: -1 }`
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8BsSi.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One very quick change that would achieve this is to simply reverse the passed in array, which will result in the earlier items being used where possible.

To avoid mutating the original array, we can create a copy with `[...objects]` and then use `.reverse()` ([documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse))

```js
function zip() {
  const appliedValues = Object.assign({}, ...[...objects].reverse());
  return appliedValues;
}


const objects = [
  { foo: 5, bar: 6 },
  { foo: 13, baz: -1 }
];

console.log(zip(...objects));
```

Comment: Thanks, but they want me to use the reduce function

Comment: @Mr.Mox Based on your question, that's unexpected.